# How do I turn a large area underground into air?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to start a new project in my creative world. I need an underground space of 80x80 and 60 up. How would I go about doing this using commands? I've tried what I think is right but it isn't working. I need to turn all the blocks in this area into air blocks.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud it seems to be asking for a simple fill command, I don't see how there's anything modded about that.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what version you’re using.

In Java you would use:
`/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:air`

With the coordinates being the outer corners of the rectangular prism that you want filled with air. If this returns with an error of being too large you can split it into a few areas in any which way you want, my recommendation would be in the y direction as you can then go 60-70, 71-80, 81-90...

Please look at [this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/fill) wiki article for specifics and extra information. Note that you don’t need to specify [destroy|hollow|keep...